# Java Simple Program

Tags: java

I am Getting Error Can You tell ME where Is the Error In This File ?

```
public class IfSample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x,y;
        x=10;
        y=20;
        if(x<y) System.out.println(“x is less than y”);
        x=x*2;
        if(x==y) System.out.println(“x now equal to y”);
        x=x*2;
        if(x>y) System.out.println(“x is greater than y”);
        // this won’t display anything.
        if(x==y) System.out.println(“you won’t see this”);
    }
 }
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: need a lend of some brackets lol?

Comment: Copy -- paste problem ?? Change the quotes... will work...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are using these quotes `“”`. That is why you're getting the error. Use the standard double quotes for Strings.

```
if (x < y)
    System.out.println("x is less than y"); // standard double quotes
x = x * 2;
if (x == y)
    System.out.println("x now equal to y");
x = x * 2;
if (x > y)
    System.out.println("x is greater than y");
// this won’t display anything.
if (x == y)
    System.out.println("you won’t see this");
```